# Не удаётся открыть файл с помощью std::ifstream

Tags: c++, классы

Хочу свою функцию для чтения/записи файлов, но оно не хочет считывать. (Не удалось открыть файл). Что не так?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 2
#define M 3
using namespace std;
class matr
{
    float x[N][M];
public:
    void vvod(char *S);
    void vivod(char *S);
    friend matr operator+(matr &a, matr &b);
};
void matr::vvod(char *S)
{
    ifstream ifs(S);
    if(ifs)
    {
        cout<< "Не открылся файл " << S << '\ n';
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
            ifs >> x[i][j];
}
void matr::vivod(char *S)
{
    ofstream ofs(S);
    for(int i = 0; i <N; i ++)
        for(int j = 0; j <M; j ++)
            ofs<< x[i][j];
}
matr operator+(matr &a,matr &b)
{
    matr z;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<M; j++)
            z.x[i][j] = a.x[i][j]+b.x[i][j];
    return z;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(0,"Russian");
    matr v, w, q;
    v.vvod("v.txt");
    w.vvod("w.txt");
    q = v+w;
    q.vivod("q.txt");
}
```

Comment: Может, у вас нет файлов v.txt и w.txt?

Comment: есть файлы, но не считывает

Answer (score 2):

Вы же не то проверяете!

```
if(ifs)
```

это проверка, что все в порядке! А вы сразу пишете, что ошибка...

Comment: Пропустил знак "!" Разобрался, благодарю всех кто помог
Заменил строчку 'if(ifs)' на 'if(!ifs)' заработало!